# Copy values from html <select multiple> to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I have this select element

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="selection">  
    <option value="test1">Test1</option> 
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

A user is complaining because they cannot copy values to their clipboard. Is there any way to make it so users can copy? I created this JSfiddle however it is not a good solution in my opinion.

http://jsfiddle.net/22gy9/4/

Comment: What you can do is to replace the `<select>` with an `<ul>` list with JavaScript. Keep the `<select>` in the DOM and replace it with JavaScript. That approach is also used when styling `<select>` dropdowns.

Comment: I believe we can't do it with just javascript, what we usually see around is a plugin that puts flash obj to do the work, see more info here: https://github.com/blog/1365-a-more-transparent-clipboard-button

Comment: Users complain. Doesn't mean you have to cater to every whim.

Comment: It is not about the _why_ but the _how_ guys. Stop the critics.

Comment: +1 for cool jsfiddle example.

Comment: btw, cool guys use FireBug to extract values from unselectable HTML elements :P

Comment: You can see the following blog which will help you to save the content to the clipboard: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html.

For IE, use the clipboardData.setData('text', s); method to save the content. For the other browsers use the flash based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it cannot be done with a button (like in your example). However it is somewhat possible by doing something like described below.

First we need a textfield, which value is editable and can be selected (this will work as our "clipboard"). A second thing we need is a way to detect if user presses CTRL (for CTRL+C). So the basic idea is to copy selected values to our textfield and when the user presses CTRL we select the contents of our textfield. Then by pressing C the user is performing a copy command on our textfield instead of the select-element.

Here's a basic implementation (check the jsfiddle below). You can fine tune it to match your needs :)

HTML

`<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="selection" onkeydown="keydown(event)" onchange="changeClipboardValue(this)" >

    <option value="test1">Test1</option> 
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="clipboard" onkeyup="keyup(event)" />`

JavaScript

`function changeClipboardValue(selectBox) {
    var clipboard = document.getElementById("clipboard");
    var text = "";
    for (i = 0; i < selectBox.length; i++) {
        if(selectBox.options[i].selected) text += selectBox.options[i].value + ",";
    }
    clipboard.value = text;
}`

`function keydown(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 17) {
        var clipboard = document.getElementById("clipboard");
        clipboard.select();
    }
}`

`function keyup(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 17) {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selection");
        selectBox.focus();
    }
}`

Might want to add CSS to hide the clipboard field
`#clipboard {width: 1px;height: 1px;padding:0;position:absolute;left:-9999px;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/LubZt/

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kcv6j/ this version works better when holding CTRL to select multiple items.

Comment: This is a good hack, it's a bit buggy though if a user selects multiple items (holding ctrl) then presses c it will not work. The user has to release ctrl then press it again in order to copy. Other that its good thinking.

Comment: Hmm, holding ctrl to select multiple works for me. What browser are you using Aaron?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem you described... Can be fixed with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Kcv6j/